# Asynchronous code in node - avoid redundant usage of async / await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a question about the usage of async / await in a Node.js project wrote in typescript.

We have a chain of functions all with async and await. And my question is:

Could we avoid all these async / await?

```
   const processed = await this.processMessage(content);

   async processMessage(message): Promise<Boolean> {
     processed = await this.process(message.data);
     return processed;
   }

   async process(data): Promise<Boolean> {
     // some async action with an await that returns a boolean, i.e. delete in database
   }
```

And do

```
   const processed = this.processMessage(content);

   processMessage(message): Boolean {
     processed = this.process(message.data);
     return processed;
   }

   process(data): Boolean {
     // some async action i.e. delete in database
   }
```

Are all these async await necessary throughout the code? Or in a case like this where we await for every asynchronous step we could use the second option instead?

Comment: no. you cannot.

Comment: No. Since `process` is asynchronous, it cannot return the boolean immediately. Please show the actual code, not `// some async action`, and we can explain in more detail.

Comment: The only redundant `await` is in `processMessage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that `processMessage` is doing is extracting the `data` property out of `message`, you can just forward the promise generated by `process` and not await the intermediate result.

```
processMessage(message): Promise<Boolean> {
  return this.process(message.data);
}
```

Comment: And `processMessage` is not an async function since it is returning a promise?

Comment: @Belen No, `processMessage` in this case is just a regular function that returns an object that happens to be a `Promise`. If you said `async processMessage` that would turn it into an async function that would implicitly wrap all return values in a `Promise` if the return value was not already an instance of a `Promise`.

Comment: @Belen https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=28&pln=10&pc=33#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFASgC4YAFAJ3QFtUQBTAHggUoCNayA+GAbwCgYYZWsgRksARgBMAZgDcvAL69eiFBixwckgsXJUaDJq3Zc+AoSLGkK1OgDohIdABsAbrVxTp+eUt6hIWFUoNEwYSmBUCAIefhgoTCdnWjtndABzXGAAd0jkbDx8ABoYHLyC7XwfRWUIqII7KGBkKAALXASIJJS09OqgA

Comment: Thanks @Jiří Pospíšil ! Good way to check it.